# Pandas : Dataframe plot rows as x value and header y values

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I would like to compare my rows values (the numbers) and add them into the same plot, where each curve is a column. I tried something but the row values are not sorted.
My Dataframe :

[image: Dataframe]

My code :

```
for name, series in df.iteritems():
      plt.plot(series, df.index)
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

What I get :

[image: algo]

Anyone can help me ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: please provide the data as **text**, not image, also the output you expect is not clear